# What would company do to me if I cheat their clients?

Tags: interviewing, company-policy, clients

I am working in a MNC since 8 months and get caught cheating when I am giving
client interview for getting into client project by using [proxy](https://www.ptechpartners.com/2020/10/15/proxy-interviews-and-fake-skype-calls-rising/). Will they **recover salary** back from me for cheating their clients?

I searched all over my offer letter and my company policy for punishments for cheating their clients but I didn't find one.

Comment: What do you mean by cheating?

Comment: Is this your regular salary or some sort of performance bonus you've 'cheated' to obtain? That might affect your employers ability to 'recover salary'.

Comment: @Kilisi I took help from **proxy** guy while attempting interview.

Comment: @Dustybin80 It's regular salary **not** a performance bonus I've 'cheated' to obtain.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you got jobs for people with clients by using a proxy to undertake the technical interview? Your employer has found out but currently the clients aren't aware?

Comment: What does MNC stand for? If you are working for company A, why do you need to give interviews to company B to be in a "client project"?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I thought this might be the case (contract to work for other companies) but is it common to have interviews to get assigned to these contracts? Genuinely asking, no experience in such posiitons

Comment: __whatever the company decides to do, we cannot predict / control this. You need a lawyer, not a bunch of random people's guesswork.__

Answer (score 5):

You have been pretty vague about what you mean by "cheating" and so it's difficult to say.  But let's assume what you have done is both against company policy and against the law.

In that case you have two concerns:

1. The company is quite likely to terminate you with cause.  Generally, illegal and even or unethical actions are things that the company views as unacceptable.  They may also file a civil action against you to recover damages.
2. They company may involve local law enforcement and turn over evidence of your "cheating" and the prosecutors may decide to pursue a case against you.  Obviously this could result in fines or even incarceration.

In either case, or in the case of both, you're not in for a good ride over this.

Comment: recover damages? I didn't even enter into client project. So explain **damages** here?

Comment: @MaxBoster You'll have explain what you mean by cheating.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I edited my question and comments what I mean by **cheating**.

Comment: @MaxBoster Damages could be about anything they consider that you have cost them by doing what you have done.  That may include the salary they paid you since you misrepresented yourself.  For example, say you present yourself as an experienced accountant and they hire you are such.  After 3 months on the job it becomes clear that you are not an accountant and have no knowledge of accounting.  The company has paid you 3 months salary as an accountant.  They may claim they are "damaged" in the amount of your salary plus any bad work you did that cost them money.  That's what I mean.

Comment: @MaxBoster - Conducting interviews costs money and time. If an individual spent say 20 hours, to hire someone for your position, it wouldn’t be unreasonable to think they could recover damages. There is a reason there is a saying that says “cheaters never win”, frankly, best to leave the company on your own terms. Yes; they could also not pay you since, it wasn’t you, who performed the work!

Answer (score 4):

Most likely they will fire you and put you on the "do not hire list". Your professional reputation will be damaged and it's going to be difficult to land your next job. Obviously you will not get a positive reference and  MNCs tend to have large networks so word gets around.

Anything above that is unlikely. Legal action and/or attempts to recover any damages is in most cases more bother than it's worth, but that depends on your specifics (country, local law, your contract, general corporate culture, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> I searched all over my offer letter and my company policy for punishments for cheating their clients but I didn't find one.

What you did damaged (well, destroyed really) the trust between you and your employer. Even in a country with very strict labor laws, that is reason to fire you for cause.

What you did also damaged the trust between the client and your employer, something that will also get you fired for cause in any country I know.

So that is what they *can* do, the question is *will* they?

The answer will be *yes*. Because if they do not condemn your actions and fire you, this will be seen as condoning your actions. And while *you* are relatively safe from actual lawsuits, because you don't have enough money to actually pay any fine of meaningful size, an MNC has deep pockets and *can* be sued for financial gain successfully.

So be prepared to be fired for cause. I don't think you left them any chance to not do that.